# htaccess wordpress rewriterule not working 404 error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm attempting to make a rewriterule for a page to load the content of another one and show the proper information.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^index\.php/file/(.*)$ index.php/file/?value=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When i put my url it shows me a 404 error but the "index.php/file/?value=$1" is working fine for me.

Any help?

EDIT:

Still not working... I've been dealing with this issue for almost a week so if someone knows how to make this work please tell me.

**EDIT 2 [SOLUTION]:**

I finally get to solve my problem. The point is that I needed to make some changes into my functions.php file from the wp theme:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_state_var', 0, 1);
function add_state_var($vars){
    $vars[] = 'value';
    return $vars;
}

add_rewrite_rule('^file/([^/]+)/?$','index.php?
pagename=file&value=$matches[1]','top');
```

and leave my .htaccess file like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope this could help somebody!

Comment: what urls you tried?

Comment: @Ben I just added the solution but thanks anyway for asking! :)

Comment: I was also wondering why nothing like this works, you have to for some reason go to Settings -> Perma Links -> click Save. I had everything correct, this ate up 2 hours of my time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We also recommend that you drop that entire RewriteRule block and replace it with the one line:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

This eliminates the complexity and fragility of the rewrites and is more efficient.