# 404 in all pages except homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I've tried all the possible solutions I've seen online and I dont know what else to do. Website is https://amigoswgr.com
I'm using Wordpress on Apache.
It all started with a security warning on both Chrome and Firefox, my hosting helped me solved it, it was an SSL issue and I had to reinstall and deploy the certificates.
Since then I can now finally access Wordpress dashboard but the front end just shows the homepage, any other page inside the website just throws a 404 error.
Seems like Apache is ignoring the content of .htaccess.
I made sure is not a permalinks issue by saving permalinks structure in WordPress settings.
My httpd.conf looks like this:

```
<Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I checked that the module mod_rewrite it's activated in apache. Next thing I did was copying my .htaccess RewriteRules into this website https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to see if there's any issue with them. My .htaccess has 2 different mod_rewrite.c sections. One is this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https
RewriteRule .* - [E=WPR_SSL:-https]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteRule .* - [E=WPR_ENC:_gzip]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !(wordpress_logged_in_.+|wp-postpass_|wptouch_switch_toggle|comment_author_|comment_author_email_) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/register/(.*)|/(.+/)?feed/?|/(?:.+/)?embed/|/checkout/(.*)|/cart/|/wc-api/v(.*)|/(index\.php/)?wp\-json(/.*|$))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(facebookexternalhit).* [NC]
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/index%{ENV:WPR_SSL}%{ENV:WPR_WEBP}.html%{ENV:WPR_ENC}" -f
RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/index%{ENV:WPR_SSL}%{ENV:WPR_WEBP}.html%{ENV:WPR_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
```

And the other one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I introduced the rewriterules in that site, theres just one throwing an error:

RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

This rule was not met.

I'd appreciate very much any help you can give me, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [htaccess wordpress rewriterule not working 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48165120/htaccess-wordpress-rewriterule-not-working-404-error)

Comment: "This rule was not met." - That's not an error. In fact, that's just highlighting a deficiency with that tool - on a real Apache server that rule is met. (Most of the rules in the first block "will not be met".) "My .htaccess has 2 different mod_rewrite.c sections." - Remove the `<IfModule>` wrapper - do you get an error? Add some nonsense to the top of the file, do you get an error?

Comment: I tried editing .htaccess with some nonsense and removing the wrapper as suggested.The site loads the same way as before, just the homepage and wordpress dashboard. Does this mean apache is bypassing the .htaccess?

Comment: "Does this mean apache is bypassing the .htaccess?" - possibly. `<Directory />` - You shouldn't be allowing access to the server route. This should be `AllowOverride None` and `Require all denied`. You should then have a more specific `<Directory>` container, perhaps in a `<VirtualHost>` block where you allow access for your site - what other relevant elements of your server config do you have?